# my JavaFX TableView Pagination keep displaying all rows

Tags: java, javafx

My JavaFX table display pagination buttons number correctly but it keep displaying all rows,while I set the rows limit to 100, **it detect the number of pages but it keep show all data and the page buttons useless since all rows are displayed** . below is my code .

[image]

my data entity model (POJO)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name = "product_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int ProductId;

@Column(name = "product_code", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String ProductCode;

@Column(name = "product_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String ProductName;



public Product(int productId, String productCode, String productName) 
{
    this.ProductId = productId;
    this.ProductCode = productCode;
    this.ProductName = productName;
}



public Product() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



public int getProductId() {
    return ProductId;
}

public void setProductId(int productId) {
    this.ProductId = productId;
}

public String getProductCode() {
    return ProductCode;
}

public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
    this.ProductCode = productCode;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return ProductName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.ProductName = productName;
}

}
```

my Controller

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private BorderPane borderpane;

@FXML
private StackPane stackpane;

@FXML
private TableView<Product> ProductTableView;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Product, Integer> clm1;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Product, String> clm2;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Product, String> clm3;

ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();

private final static int dataSize = 200;
private final static int rowsPerPage = 100;

private final ObservableList<Product> dataList = 
FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ArrayList<Product>
(rowsPerPage));

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    ProductTableView.setItems(dataList);
    clm1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ProductId"));
    clm2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>
    ("ProductCode"));
    clm3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>
    ("ProductName"));

    Pagination pagination = new Pagination((dataSize / rowsPerPage + 
    1), 0);
    progressIndicator.setMaxSize(800, 200);
    //borderpane.getChildren().add(ProductTableView);
    //stackpane.getChildren().add(ProductTableView);
    stackpane.getChildren().add(progressIndicator);

    pagination.setPageFactory((final Integer pageIndex) -> {
        progressIndicator.setVisible(true);

        dataList.clear();

        // long running background task
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int fromIndex = pageIndex * rowsPerPage;
                    int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + rowsPerPage, 
                    dataSize);

                    List<Product> loadedList = loadData(fromIndex, 
                    toIndex);

                    Platform.runLater(() -> 
                    dataList.setAll(loadedList));

                } finally {

                    Platform.runLater(() -> 
                    progressIndicator.setVisible(false));

                }
            }
        }.start();

        //fixed it was saying "return borderpane"!!!
        return ProductTableView;
    });



     BorderPane borderpane = new BorderPane(pagination);

    stackpane.getChildren().add(borderpane);
    }

    private List<Product> loadData(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    Session session =  
    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Product");

    //List<Product> list = 
    query.list();//getAllProductsDatabase().list();
    // List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
    List<Product> list = query.list();
    // list = query.list();
    try {
    for(Product productlist:list){
     System.out.println(productlist.getProductId()+" 
    "+productlist.getProductCode()+" "+productlist.getProductName());

     }
    Thread.sleep(201);}
    catch( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Size: "+ list.size());
    return list;
    }

    @FXML
    private void onTableClick(MouseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Click");

    Product selectedId = 
    ProductTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println(selectedId.getProductId());
    System.out.println(selectedId.getProductCode());
    System.out.println(selectedId.getProductName());
}



}
```

my `FXML`

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="800.0" maxWidth="1000.0" prefHeight="800.0" 
prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="application.SampleController">
 <children>
  <BorderPane maxHeight="800.0" maxWidth="1000.0" prefHeight="800.0" 
    prefWidth="900.0">
     <top>
        <StackPane fx:id="stackpane" maxWidth="800.0" 
         prefHeight="1000.0" prefWidth="900.0" 
             BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
           <children>
              <TableView fx:id="ProductTableView" 
               onMouseClicked="#onTableClick" maxHeight="800.0" 
               maxWidth="1000.0" prefHeight="800.0" 
               prefWidth="1000.0">
                <columns>
                  <TableColumn fx:id="clm1" prefWidth="102.0" 
                    text="Product ID" />
                    <TableColumn fx:id="clm2" prefWidth="123.0" 
                    text="Product Code" />
                    <TableColumn fx:id="clm3" prefWidth="164.0" 
                    text="Product Column" />
                    </columns>
                    </TableView>
               </children>
            </StackPane>
         </top>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't set the limits `fromIndex` and `toIndex`, I think This code will fix your problem just Change `loadData(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` Method to this.

```
private List<Product> loadData(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    Session session =  
    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Product P WHERE P.id >= " + fromIndex + " AND P.id < " + toIndex);

    List<Product> list = query.list();
    try {
        for(Product productlist:list){
         System.out.println(productlist.getProductId()+" 
        "+productlist.getProductCode()+" "+productlist.getProductName());

         }
        Thread.sleep(201);
    }catch( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Size: "+ list.size());
    return list;
    }
```

What I did, I changed this.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Product");
```

To this.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Product P WHERE P.id >= " +
 fromIndex + " AND P.id < " + toIndex);
```

### Edit 1

To get Exactly 100 rows even if you deleted a row you have to use this code.

here is the code to do that:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Product P")
.setFirstResult(fromIndex)
.setMaxResults(100);
```

> The first method:

```
setFirstResult(fromIndex)
```

Set the position of the first result to retrieve.
And `fromIndex`is the position of the first result, numbered from 0.

> The second method:

```
setMaxResults(100)
```

Set the maximum number of results to retrieve.
100 is the maximum number of results to retrieve.

Comment: thanks it worked , I didn't expect the issue is related to my Hibernate Query  :)

Comment: You're Welcome Bro

Comment: I have added a delete button recently to the table above...now after I delete 1 row for the first page which display 100 rows instead it display 99 rows...what actually should happened is 1 row shifted from the second page to the first page and display 100 rows . I think that because of the Hibernate select using ID not row ...I'm not able to solve it till now ....also I don't know how to refresh the table after I delete one row ? hope you have an idea .

Comment: Thanks bro this way is working for me  :)...I'm stuck at refreshing the table after I delete or edit the row ...I have created my own method to refresh the table but I think it's a bad method . this is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804824/best-practice-to-refresh-table-with-pagination-in-javafx-and-hibernate   hope you can help :)